# numpy advanced indexing with array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a simple indexing need that I have no idea how to use numpy  to achieve it. It's usually the case that we have two dimensional array of `E` with shape`(N,C)`, and one dimensional array of `y` with shape`(N)`, which is a `label` matrix, when computing the `softmax loss`, there is a widely used operation: `E[range(N),y]-=1`, this is very efficient code, Now I have a more generalized problem, that I have array `E` of shape`(C,H,W)` and label y of shape`(H,W)`, now `C` axis is the first axis and there is `3 dimension`, how can I do the similar operation like `E[range(H,W), y]-=1`

Comment: @Divakar, as per numpy: Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with basic slicing that returns a view)., I want to change the value of original array with advanced indexing, how can I do it?

Comment: It should work when assigning. So, simply index and assign.

Comment: Tried it on my case, can you points where I'm wrong: 
`grid = np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, y.shape))]`
then `grid.insert(0, idx)`
then `E[tuple(grid)]-=1`
prompts:`*** IndexError: index 65535 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2`

Comment: Why not try the func itself : `arr[all_idx(idx, axis)] = new_values`? Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, in my case I replace `idx` with `y`, and `axis` with `0`, is that right?

Comment: Yes and `arr` with `E` I suppose.

Comment: @Divakar, thank you, turns out it is my problem, that label is out of range:)